# Images are being filtered on a generic site that shares the same IP address with an adult site

Tags: google, filtering, adult-content

I recently [addressed the community](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58182/google-image-safe-search-filters-my-images-what-should-i-do-to-prevent-this-pro) to understand why normal images are being filtered by Google Image Search.

I have several sites placed on the same server (and that they all definitely share the same IP address) and one of those sites has *Adult* content on it. I am now assuming that the filtering problem might be caused by the fact that the generic site shares the same IP address as the adult site.

If I remove the adult site from being hosted or from this IP address, will it solve my filtering problem for the rest of my sites?
What else can I do besides the removal of mentioned adult site from that IP address?

Answer (score 1):

Just removing the adult site from that IP address won't cause your images to start popping up immediately in normal image search results.

A better option would be to maybe move the normal sites to a different IP address and let the Adult site sit on that IP address.

It is possible that the IP address has been marked as being a host for Adult content and it may take a while for that status to change.